# Symfony 5 : In ExceptionConverter.php line 117 : An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, doctrine, symfony5

Problem : When i create a new db with cli symfony console doctrine:database:create, i am getting these errors :

```
    extension=mysqli
    extension=pdo_mysql

: are free from any ;
```

i tried every version of php and xampp and still the same problem : i currantly on version 8.1.6 for both php and Xampp i do only have one php.ini in the Xampp/php file and i did try'd to revoume every comment related

the symfony serve is running fine i tried coding in it doing roots every thing is fine in it except database creating
.Xampp is runnig both MySQL and Appache fine as well
i'm using windows 10 .

```
symfony console doctrine:database:create

In ExceptionConverter.php line 117:

An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver  


In Exception.php line 28:

could not find driver


In Driver.php line 28:

could not find driver
```

the .env file

```
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/EspritClub" // i don't have mdp for the phpmyadmin 
 #DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=14&charset=utf8"
```

Hope i give all the information , i really need to solve this it has been a week now and still nothing changed .

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolve it , So the problem was in the php.ini file i was changing in the one that was in Xampp/php cause i did not have php.ini in the main php file so i just copy paste the php.ini the the main file and it worked .
[image]